# Управление веб сервером LAMP по SSH из-под Windows в локальной сети

Tags: linux, windows, ssh

У меня есть два компа, на одном стоит windows 10, а на другой я поставил Ubuntu 14.04.

Компьютер с виндой для выхода в интернет запитан шнурком с роутера, а комп с линуксом соединяется через WiFi. На линуксе я поставил сервер LAMP.

Я хочу подключиться к линуксу с компа, на котором у меня стоит винда. Как это сделать?

P.S. Я новичок в этой области, учусь системному администрированию, так что, если можно, объясните, пожалуйста, более подробно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для начала вам понадобится установить на второй из компьютеров пакет *openssh-server*:

```
$ sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

если такой пакет уже установлен, ничего «страшного» не произойдёт.

---

скорее всего, оба ваших комьютера находятся в одном широковещательном ethernet-сегменте. потому вы сможете добраться до второго компьютера по его ip-адресу.

узнать ip-адрес на сетевом интерфейсе в операционной системе *gnu/linux* можно с помощью, например, такой команды (приведён и пример её вывода):

```
$ ip a | grep 'inet '
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
inet 192.168.0.123/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global wlan0
```

здесь `127.0.0.1` — это адрес, закреплённый за интерфейсом `lo` (имя интерфейса — последнее слово в строках), это локальный loopback-интерфейс.
а адрес `192.168.0.123` — это адрес, закреплённый за интерфейсом `wlan0` (тут может быть и другая цифра, и имя несколько отличаться: например, `wifi0` и т.п.).

вот по этому адресу вам и надо подключаться по протоколу [*ssh*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH), воспользовавшись на первом из компьютеров, например, программой [*putty*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY).

при подключении надо будет указать ещё имя пользователя (и, разумеется, пароль этого пользователя). если вы не знаете имени, то его можно узнать, например, командой:

```
$ whoami
```

---

после удачного подключения вы получите рабочую оболочку ([*shell*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B)), где и можете выполнять любые действия по управлению вашим вторым комьютером.

Comment: я очень Вам благодарен за ответ, а то в интернете я чет ничего понятного не вычитал, а Вы объяснили все очень доступно. Еще раз благодарю Вас.